# Should I notify a user if I make a reference to the users comment my answer

Tags: discussion

Often users post good information about problems with OPs code in a comment. That is, they point to something which is wrong but they don't want to write a complete answer.

If I have something significant to add, I might write an answer which - besides my own findings - also includes the findings from the comment (in order to make the answer as complete as possible). I try to remember to give credit by writing something like: As mentioned by @user there also is a problem with ....

I know that writing @user inside the answer doesn't send a notification to @user. So now I'm wondering whether or not I should use a comment to notify the user.

Would that be considered

a) good behavior

or

b) unnecessary/unwanted noise

Comment: I don't think that a comment is necessary.

Comment: I normally say: as pointed out by `@username` do foo. where `@username` is a link to that user.  I do not link to the actual comments as those can be/are deleted and I prefer to not have a dead link.

Comment: How do you know they wouldn't want to fix the mistake if you pointed it out?

Comment: @Laurel - I'm not sure I understand your comment. Are you suggesting that I should *not* include others findings their from comments?

Comment: I agree with [@NathanOliver](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver) though, I will link to the comment if I don't quote the entire thing.

Comment: @4386427 I guess I misunderstood what you were asking. I thought you were talking about comments on an answer, not those annoying "comment answers".